# How can I close a tkinter window when changing to a pygame window?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am creating a game using both tkinter and pygame and I don't know how to close a tkinter window when the program launches pygame from the menu. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

```
# Importing Widgets and from different modules:
import Customised_Widgets as cw
# Importing the libraries required to operate the program:
import pygame as py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import DOG_BackEnd as be

LARGE_FONT = ("Comic Sans MS", 20) # Font for large text selected

# Classes that help create all the menus using tkinter


class Dog(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/D.O.G.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "D.O.G.")
        tk.Tk.wm_geometry(self, "960x720")
        tk.Tk.wm_resizable(self, False, False)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        """self.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Fonts/Menu Font.png")
        self.image2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Fonts/Options Font.png")
        self.image3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Fonts/Paused Font.png")"""

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainMenu, PauseMenu, OptionsMenu):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(MainMenu)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

The MainMenu

```
class MainMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        tk.Frame.configure(self, background="#99D9EA")

        self.menu_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Project Design/Slide1.png")

        tk.Label(self, image=self.menu_image).place(x=0, y=0)

        button1 = cw.Button(self, default="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Main Menu/Play Button.gif",
                            hover="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Main Menu/Play Button 2.gif",
                            highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="#99D9EA", bd=0, borderwidth=0, activebackground="#99D9EA", command=be.Game)
        button1.place(x=660, y=215)

        button2 = cw.Button(self, default="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Main Menu/Options Button.gif",
                            hover="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Main Menu/Options Button 2.gif",
                            highlightbackground="#99D9EA", activebackground="#99D9EA", bd=0, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(OptionsMenu))
        button2.place(x=660, y=293)

        button3 = cw.Button(self, default="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Main Menu/Exit Button.gif",
                            hover="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Main Menu/Exit Button 2.gif",
                            highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="#99D9EA", borderwidth=0, bd=0, command=lambda: controller.destroy())
        button3.place(x=660, y=366)
```

The OptionsMenu

```
class OptionsMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        tk.Frame.configure(self, background="#99D9EA")

        self.menu_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Project Design/Slide2.png")

        tk.Label(self, image=self.menu_image).place(x=0, y=0)

        button1 = cw.Button(self, default="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Options Menu/Music Button.gif",
                            hover="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Options Menu/Music Button 2.gif",
                            highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="#99D9EA", bd=0, borderwidth=0, activebackground="#99D9EA", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(OptionsMenu))
        button1.place(x=414, y=129)

        button2 = cw.Button(self, default="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Options Menu/SFX Button.gif",
                            hover="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Options Menu/SFX Button 2.gif",
                            highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="#99D9EA", bd=0, borderwidth=0, activebackground="#99D9EA", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(OptionsMenu))
        button2.place(x=414, y=210)

        button3 = cw.Button(self, default="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Options Menu/Location Button.gif",
                            hover="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Options Menu/Location Button 2.gif",
                            highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="#99D9EA", bd=0, borderwidth=0, activebackground="#99D9EA", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(OptionsMenu))
        button3.place(x=414, y=291)

        button4 = cw.Button(self, default="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Options Menu/Exit Button.gif",
                            hover="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Buttons/Options Menu/Exit Button 2.gif",
                            activebackground="#EED9EA", highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="#99D9EA", borderwidth=0, bd=0, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainMenu))
        button4.place(x=414, y=371)
```

The PauseMenu

```
class PauseMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        tk.Frame.configure(self, background="#99D9EA")

        self.menu_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Project Design/Slide3.png")

        tk.Label(self, image=self.menu_image).place(x=0, y=0)

        button1 = cw.Button(self, text="-", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainMenu))
        button1.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Dog()
    root.mainloop()
```

(The Classes are all in the same File, I split the code for better readability)

The code here is the back end of my program, this module contains all of my pygame code:

```
import DOG_FrontEnd
import pygame as py, sys
from pygame.locals import *


displayw = 960
displayh = 720

py.display.set_caption("Don't Over Grill (D.O.G)")

screen = py.display.set_mode((displayw, displayh), 0, 32)

clock = py.time.Clock()

player_sprite = py.image.load("N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game 
Files/Sprites/Ishmael/Running/Run 1.png")
player_sprite2 = py.image.load("N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game 
Files/Sprites/Shiba/Stationary 1.png")
background = py.image.load("N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/Map/Desert Map 1.png")
icon = py.image.load("N:/ICT/A levels/Year 13/NEA/Game Files/D.O.G.ico")

py.display.set_icon(icon)


class Game:
    py.init()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.done = False
        self.close()

    def close(self):
        while not self.done:
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(player_sprite, (20, 450))
            for event in py.event.get():
                if event.type == py.QUIT:
                    self.done = True

                py.display.flip()

        py.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
```

The code here is my class to import custom buttons for my tkinter window:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Button(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, default="", hover="", **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master=parent, **kwargs)
        self.default = tk.PhotoImage(file=default)
        self.hover = tk.PhotoImage(file=hover)
        self.configure(image=self.default)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.configure(image=self.default)

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.configure(image=self.hover)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about when this is supposed to happen, and which Tkinter-window you want to close. Maybe I just couldn't spot where it is supposed to be?

But you could start off with `window_name.destroy()`. That should close the given window.
You seem to use that function already, soo that should work for you then?

I could find where you actually use `pygame`. There is no line of code using this library am I right?

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't include the back end because I didn't see it necessary to include since what I need help is closing the tkinter window upon the program launching the pygame window but i'll edit to include anyways. Thanks for your help.